# Split string on [:punct:] except for underscore in R

Tags: regex, r, math, strsplit

I have an equation as a string where the variables in the string equation are variables in the R workspace. I would like to replace each variable with its numeric value in the R workspace. This is easy enough when the variable names don't contain punctuation.

Here is a simple example.

```
x <- 5
y <- 10
yy <- 15
z <- x*(y + yy)
zAsChar <- "z=x*(y+yy)"
vars <- unlist(strsplit(zAsChar, "[[:punct:]]"))
notVars <- unlist(strsplit(zAsChar, "[^[:punct:]]"))
varsValues <- sapply(vars[vars != ""], FUN=function(aaa) get(aaa))
notVarsValues <- notVars[notVars != ""]
paste(paste0(varsValues, notVarsValues), collapse="")
```

This yields `"125=5*(10+15)"`, which is great.

However, I would love the option to use underscores in the variable names so that I can use "subscripts" for variable names. I am using these strings in math mode in R markdown.

So I need a `[:punct:]` that excludes `_`. I tried using `[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\(\\)\\=]` rather than `[:punct:]`, but with this approach I couldn't split on the minus sign. Is there a way to preserve the `_`?

Comment: `x <- 5; y<- 10;yy <- 15;z <- x*(y+yy); sprintf('%s = %s * (%s + %s)', z, x, y, yy)`?

Comment: @rawr - Thanks, this works, too. I prefer the option to convert the string equation. But you're answering the question I _should_ have asked. I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879083/make-r-markdown-code-blocks-into-math-mode), but didn't too much response, so I figured I was asking the wrong question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `[:punct:]` use the unicode character class `\pP` *(shortcut for `\p{P}`)* and its negation `\PP` to do that:

```
[^\\PP_]
```

(It works with `perl=TRUE` option)

Comment: Should this include `+`, `-`, and `=`? I am still not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to do all this string manipulation? The `substitute()` function can help you out

```
substitute(z==x*(y+yy), list(x=x, y=y, yy=yy,z=z))
```

Or if you really need to start with a character value

```
do.call("substitute", list(parse(text=zAsChar)[[1]],list(x=x, y=y, yy=yy,z=z)))
# 125 = 5 * (10 + 15)
```

You can `deparse()` the result to turn it back into a character.

Comment: Thanks! This is the question I _should_ have asked.